# How to convert JavaFX project to Maven correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, fxml

I wrote JavaFx project in Eclipse IDE, it worked correctly.

Once I converted it into Maven project, my FMXL files stopped opening. However, if I create new FXML files and put them in the same folders, everything works.

Is there any way to run my Maven project without recreating all my FXML files?

I've already tried changing paths to my FXML files in code, moving FXMLs to src/main/resources package or simply copying the code from old FXMLs to the new ones, but nothing worked.

All FXMLs I created in SceneBuilder and haven't changed the version of this program  throughout the process.

I'm loading my FXMLs using the following method:

```
private void showMainPage() throws IOException {
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainView.fxml"));
mainLayout = loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}
```

my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fx</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>fxMaven</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>17</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.36.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.5</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>ru.jfxreselection.App</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>src/main/java</directory>
              <includes>
                  <include>**/*.fxml</include>
              </includes>
      </resource>
  </resources>   
</build>
```

the error I get trying to run with old .FXML files

> Exception in Application start method
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
> java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
> method   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) Caused by:
> javafx.fxml.LoadException:
> /C:/Users/Tormo/eclipse-workspace/rslFxNewMaven/target/classes/reselection/view/MainView.fxml:48
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
> at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
> at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
> at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)   at
> rslFxNewMaven/reselection.Main.showMainPage(Main.java:28)   at
> rslFxNewMaven/reselection.Main.start(Main.java:22)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
> ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException:
> Unable to make private void
> reselection.view.MainViewController.goDacSearch() throws
> java.io.IOException accessible: module rslFxNewMaven does not "opens
> reselection.view" to module javafx.fxml   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMethods(FXMLLoader.java:3611)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3543)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor$1.run(FXMLLoader.java:3536)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.addAccessibleMembers(FXMLLoader.java:3535)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerAccessor.getControllerMethods(FXMLLoader.java:3494)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:573)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:781)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2924)
> at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2639)
> ... 13 more Exception running application reselection.Main

Comment: Stack traces are easier to read if you post them formatted as code rather than comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to Maven, it is an access error caused by incorrect configuration of the Java module system for your application.

The error message tells you what is wrong:

```
module rslFxNewMaven does not "opens reselection.view" to module javafx.fxml
```

Study -> [java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Add the following line to your module-info.java:

```
opens reselection.view to javafx.fxml;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. 

Sorry for the stacktrace format, it's my first post here :)